# Solve and find $e^{xA}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve and find $e^{xA}:$

$\left ( \begin{matrix}
    x'(t)  \\
    y'(t)\\
   \end{matrix} \right )=\left ( \begin{matrix}
    6 & -3 \\
    2 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right )\left ( \begin{matrix}
    x(t)  \\
    y(t)\\
   \end{matrix} \right ),A=\left ( \begin{matrix}
    6 & -3 \\
    2 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right)$

The eigenvalues are : $3,4$

The eigenvectors are : $\bigg \{ \left ( \begin{matrix}
    1  \\
    1\\
   \end{matrix} \right )$ , $\left ( \begin{matrix}
    1.5  \\
    1\\
   \end{matrix} \right )\bigg \}$

Then,

$y(t)=c_1e^{3t}\left ( \begin{matrix}
    1  \\
    1\\
   \end{matrix} \right )+c_2e^{4t}\left ( \begin{matrix}
    1.5  \\
    1\\
   \end{matrix} \right )$

Denote $$\phi(t)=\left ( \begin{matrix}
    e^{3t} & 1.5e^{4t} \\
    e^{3t} & e^{4t} \\
   \end{matrix} \right ) \implies \phi(t)^{-1}=\left ( \begin{matrix}
    e^{4t} & -1.5e^{4t} \\
    -e^{3t} & e^{3t} \\
   \end{matrix} \right ) $$

$e^{tA}=\phi(t)\cdot \phi^{-1}(0)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{3t}-1.5e^{4t}&-1.5e^{3t}+1.5e^{4t}\\ e^{3t}-e^{4t}&-1.5e^{3t}+e^{4t}\end{pmatrix}$

Is my solution correct?

In addition I don't get why $e^{xA}=\phi(t)\cdot \phi^{-1}(0)$ , I'll be grateful for an exlpanation.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not correct. Let$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&3/2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$(the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors). So,$$\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}AP,$$and therefore$$A=P\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}.$$So,\begin{align}\exp(tA)&=P\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}3t&0\\0&4t\end{bmatrix}\right)P^{-1}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}-2 e^{3 t}+3 e^{4 t} & 3 e^{3 t}-3 e^{4 t} \\ -2 e^{3 t}+2 e^{4 t} & 3 e^{3 t}-2 e^{4 t}\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer , In general, $e^{xA}=\phi(t)\cdot \phi^{-1}(0)$  isn't correct ?

Comment: I suppose that you meant $e^{tA}$. Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Then why my answer isn't correct ? we get different $e^{tA}$ , could you see where am I wrong please? The difference between both $e^{tA}$ is multiply by $-2$.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Where does$$\phi(t)=\begin{bmatrix}    e^{3t} & 1.5e^{4t} \\    e^{3t} & e^{4t} \end{bmatrix}$$come from?

Comment: $\phi(t)$ is the elementary matrix of the solutions.

Comment: I don't know that concept. On the other hand, you can easily check that if$$(x(t),y(t))=\begin{bmatrix}-2 e^{3 t}+3 e^{4 t} & 3 e^{3 t}-3 e^{4 t} \\ -2 e^{3 t}+2 e^{4 t} & 3 e^{3 t}-2 e^{4 t}\end{bmatrix}.(a,b),$$then $(x(0),y(0))=(a,b)$ and that $(x'(t),y'(t))=A.(x(t),y(t))$.